# Swagger. OpenAPI 3. Several specs in one ymal file

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am using Swagger 3 and generating doc by gradle plugin (https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin).

Let's say I have 4 endpoints.
I want separate them basing on the uri.
Let's say endpoint 1-2 have uri like "/api/v1/" and endpoint 3-4 have uri like "/api/v1/something"
I want have them separated in the Swagger UI into 2 groups. I can not use tags because they are already used for separation inside one group.

When I was generating docs from Java/Spring I used springfox which allowed me to do the next thing:

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket swaggerSomeGroup() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("SomeGroup")
            .tags(sometags)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("somepackage"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/v1/something/**"))
            .build()
        ////
}

 @Bean
public Docket swaggerSomeOtherGroup() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .groupName("SomeOtherGroup")
            .tags(sometags)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("somepackage"))
            .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.ant("/api/v1/something/**")))
            .build()
        ////
}
```

As a result I could choose needed spec from dropdown menu in Swagger UI.
[image]

Can I do the same but in yml and swagger generator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible be the means of code generation plugin. Only possible solution is modify UI swagger.